# 64bit Java does not work, 32bit does

Tags: java

I **had** 32 and 64bit versions of Java installed (versions 7 and 8 of both JDK and JRE [it was useless installing it twice, but installed it anyway]).

When I would exe java.exe in all of the 64bit installs (\Program Files), it would give me something like "Java SE has stopped Working" and just wouldn't do anything. Although, all of the 32bit installs would work perfectly (\Program Files (x86))

I have a 64bit install of Windows 8.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMPa0.png

It doesn't bother me that much, but id like to take advantage of all my RAM, and not just some of it.

Thank you for any replies in advance.

Comment: Have you set `JAVA_HOME` in environment variable?

Comment: Why are you executing java.exe anyway? make sure JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH are configured in Windows environment variables correctly. then go to command prompt and type java -version to confirm is java is installed.

Comment: @Glenn-- I set JAVA_HOME to the 64bit jdk8, set Path to $JAVA_HOME and "Java Platform SE binary has stopped working" .

Comment: @EvanWeissman Not that value. The location of that Java SDK should be set in `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @Anirudh http://i.imgur.com/1OmkSCU.png

Comment: @Glenn-- You mean JDK? Look at my screenshot above.

Comment: You should set JAVA_HOME under "User variables for Evan"

Comment: Did you try reinstall? Broken installation? which version of jdk?

Comment: @Anirudh Still not working. Set JAVA_HOME under Evan and set it to the JDK directory. Same error.

Comment: @hutingung I have JDK 8 and 7 for both 32 and 64bit, I currently only have 8 64bit installed and both 8 and 7 32 bit installed. I have a 7 64 bit installer ready in my downloads folder.

Comment: ok. you try this. Open command prompt. cd to jdk installation folder. run command. java -version for each installation. Post your screenshots.

Comment: Windows environment variable names are not prefixed with a `$`! That should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: @hutingung https://imgur.com/a/LWUf5 It seems no version works now. I made an error in my tests, it just uses the same one. when i go into the jre bin folder in jdk, it works

Comment: java.exe is reside in the bin folder. So, you can identify which java is working or not working? Try to reinstall the one not working.  Another fundamental thing you need to understand is OS's path. For windows, you can echo %PATH% to check. If you registered the program into the path, you can execute it anywhere. *If multiple exists, only one execute. Based on Windows's convention, C:\Windows\System32 is default path. So, some program will copy their exe into that folder. Java is one of it. You can check the properties of that java.exe and you can know exactly which installation it refer to.

Comment: @hutingung I'll try the java in sys32 folder trick. Worked for 32bit .exe WHEN all 64 bit installed were uninstalled.

Comment: Can you reinstall 64bit jdk, and use command prompt to execute <program files>/<jdk installation>/bin/java.exe ?

Comment: It is hard to get two different versions of Java to work on the same box -- can be done, but takes more than simply changing `cd`.

Comment: @HotLicks, I got 6 versions of JDK installed in my machine. I just use absolute path of java to choose which JDK I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the **path** set correctly for the java binaries to run.

From [JDK Installation for Microsoft Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#A1097936):

```
Updating the PATH Environment Variable

If you do not set the PATH variable, you need to specify the full path to the executable file every time you run it, such as:

C:\> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac" MyClass.java

It is useful to set the PATH variable permanently so it will persist after rebooting.

To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the jdk1.8.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path looks something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. Set the PATH variable as follows on Microsoft Windows:

    Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.    
    Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.

    Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation to the PATH variable in System Variables. The following is a typical value for the PATH variable:

    C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin

Note:

    The PATH environment variable is a series of directories separated by semicolons (;) and is not case-sensitive. Microsoft Windows looks for programs in the PATH directories in order, from left to right.    
    You should only have one bin directory for a JDK in the path at a time. Those following the first instance are ignored.    
    If you are not sure where to add the JDK path, append it.    
    The new path takes effect in each new command window you open after setting the PATH variable.
```

You need to have the **classpath** set correctly for javac to compile.

See [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: Thanks, compiling and the "java" command worked when in Administrator CMD prompt, and then weirdly started working in non admin cmd prompt. I dont know why, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Install  JDK 32 bit version of latest java and set **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** variables like below.

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
PATH : C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin
```

Hope this would be help

Answer (score -1):

Both JRE 32-bit and 64-bit needs to be installed, then IE will detect Java Plug-in Helper as compatible.

See release notes for Java 7 Update 55:

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release7_changes.xml

"There is a special case for 64-bit Windows - EPM (Enhanced Protected Mode)requires both 32-bit and 64-bit Plug-in installed. Please make sure you have both 32-bit and 64-bit JRE installed, otherwise there will be a warning from IE, but Java Plug-in will still run under EPM."